# Setting JavaScript variables before the opening <html> tag

Tags: java, php, javascript, variables

I have several PHP variables that I need to transfer to JavaScript.  Currently, most of my PHP code is performed as soon as the page loads, before the opening -html- tag.  If I use echo to create javascript variables before the  tag, will they be stored correctly?  Are there reasons why I would not want to do this?

Comment: Mixing PHP with HTML? That should be done in the smallest amounts possible and certainly not for any complex logic, or setting JS variables. HTML&JS -> Client Side, PHP -> Server Side. Keep that as strict as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You might not have any problems by assigning JS variables before the opening HTML tag, but if you don't, you're using some really non standards-compliant browsers. ;-)

General rule is that everything you define on a page should be either in the `<head>` or the `<body>`. Everything else should be counted as a mistake as it does not have defined behavior. Undefined behavior leads to badness.

If you put it as the first thing in the `<head>`, you should be fine though.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the variables in memory until the `<script>` tag is output in the HTML tag:

```
<?php
    ...

    // I want to transfer: $my_var
?>
...
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var php_var = <?php echo json_encode($my_var); ?>;
        </script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use echo to create the variables inside a script tag inside the html tag. What is the problem you are having?